# retrieve meta description from database yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a website made with yii framework, I want add the meta tag "description" on head of my html page, I have the structure of database with a column for ID (numbers) of page and another column with the description of page `page_description`.

Now I want retrieve for every page loaded the column `page_description` where the ID are equal to actual page Loaded in front end, I have read the documentation to create a mysql query on this page:

> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

but I didn't found a solution for retrieve the ID of actual loaded page in front end.

How I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you should make a table of meta`descriptions`

```
id (primary) int 11
page (unique) char 255
content (text)
```

Records should be

```
id    |    page    |   content
-------------------------------
1     |  home      |    welcome, bla bla bla
2     |  about-us  |    about us, bla bla bla
3     |  contact-us|    contact us, bla bla bla
```

and so on.

So on `BaseController`, in constructor you need to

- Get page from current url
- Find relevant description
- Set to relevant variable
- Variable to view
- In view, that variable to relevant tag

Comment: i have some pages with same name because i have multi-language, the only difference between URL are the ID of country like mydomain.com/de/name-of-pages, I must therefore use the unique ID of the page

Comment: Then definitely you need to save page along their tokens like `about-us-en`, `about-us-fr`, `about-en-de`

Comment: Further, if you have page ID in URL then you can go along that `IDs`